# How to change theme whenever select value from listpicker in wp8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, themes

In my windows phone 8 application, I have theme setting's page like below:

[image]

In the listpicker control I have two values `Dark` and `Light`. And when I select `Dark` from listpicker control I want to change the theme of the application:

And In the `themelistPicker1_SelectionChanged` method, I am doing like below:

```
private void themelistPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListPickerItem lpi = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as ListPickerItem;
            themename = lpi.Content.ToString();
            if (themename == "Dark")
            {
              App.dark();
            }
            else 
            {
                App.light();
            }
        }
```

And in the `App.xaml.cs` page I have define `Dark` and `Light` method defined like below:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Resources;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GetContacts.Resources;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace GetContacts
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Provides easy access to the root frame of the Phone Application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The root frame of the Phone Application.</returns>
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the Application object.
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            // Global handler for uncaught exceptions.
            UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

            // Standard XAML initialization
            InitializeComponent();

            // Phone-specific initialization
            InitializePhoneApplication();
            // Language display initialization
            InitializeLanguage();

            // Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // Display the current frame rate counters.
                Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;

                // Show the areas of the app that are being redrawn in each frame.
                //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true;

                // Enable non-production analysis visualization mode,
                // which shows areas of a page that are handed off to GPU with a colored overlay.
                //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true;

                // Prevent the screen from turning off while under the debugger by disabling
                // the application's idle detection.
                // Caution:- Use this under debug mode only. Application that disables user idle detection will continue to run
                // and consume battery power when the user is not using the phone.
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
            }
        }
        public static void dark()
        {
            (App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Color.FromArgb(12, 12, 54, 145);
            (App.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.White;
            (App.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Gray;
        }
        public static void light()
        {
            (App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Color.FromArgb(12, 12, 54, 145);
            (App.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Black;
            (App.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.White;
        }

    }
}
```

But when I select `Dark` theme `PhoneBackgroundBrush=Black` instead of `Gray` and `PhoneForegroundBrush=white` and when I select `Light` theme `PhoneBackgroundBrush=Black` instead of `White` and `PhoneForegroundBrush=Black`.

Kindly suggest me what I should do, to change the application theme after selection of value from listpicker control,do you have any idea? waiting for reply.

Thanks

Comment: Did you go through this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769545(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea. Use **[ThemeManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneThemeManager.Source/)** developed by [Jeff Wilcox](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/)
By using ThemeManager you can change theme of Application.

Install ThemeManager Library in Nuget Packages & change your code like this..

```
private void themelistPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListPickerItem lpi = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as ListPickerItem;
            themename = lpi.Content.ToString();
            if (themename == "Dark")
            {
              ThemeManager.ToDarkTheme();
            }
            else 
            {
              ThemeManager.ToLightTheme();
            }
        }
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: theme manager is working fine but when I select `Dark` theme `PhoneBackgroundBrush=Black` instead of `Gray`. why? and its not effect all over the application.

Comment: Just explore thememanager class to customize the theme. There is a method `Setbackground`. You can try like this...
`ThemeManager.SetBackground(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray));`